# How to overwrite python dictionary values?

Tags: python, dictionary, overwrite

A simplification of my dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
    'DOC': [
        [('k', 'v'), ('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k4', 'v4')],
        [('k5', 'v5'), ('k', 'v'), ('k1', 'v1'), ('k6', 'v6')]
    ],
    'DIC': [
        [('k7', 'v7'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k8', 'v8')],
        [('k5', 'v5'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2')],
        [('k4', 'v4'), ('k9', 'v9')]
    ],
    'INFRA': [
        [('k5', 'v5'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2')],
        [('k', 'v'), ('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k4', 'v4')]
    ]
}
```

Overwriting my dictionary values:

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
     my_dict[k] = map(lambda x: dict(x), my_dict[k])
```

Returning...

```
my_dict 
{'DIC': [{'k3': 'v3', 'k7': 'v7', 'k8': 'v8'},
         {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'k5': 'v5'},
         {'k4': 'v4', 'k9': 'v9'}],
 'DOC': [{'k': 'v', 'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4'},
         {'k': 'v', 'k1': 'v1', 'k5': 'v5', 'k6': 'v6'}],
 'INFRA': [{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'k5': 'v5'},
           {'k': 'v', 'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4'}]}
```

When I ran my real code following the same logic I got the error:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required

I've tried to create another dictionary to receive the `map()` but the same error occurred. Someone could help me?

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Can you show an example that causes the `ValueError`?

Comment: It's really hard to find bugs in code you can't see. `:(`

Comment: Aside: `{k: map(dict,v) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems()}` is a little simpler (2.7; `.items()` in 3).  The `lambda` is unnecessary and you're not using `v` even though you extract it.

Comment: Replace your `lambda` with a regular function which prints its argument before returning `dict(x)` and note the last thing printed before the error.

Comment: @martineau: I found something that really does not proceed. I'll report as soon as possible...

Comment: @Jason Orendorff: The problem seems more likely in the data we can't see.

Comment: Why are you doing this, because it doesn't appear to really do anything except take the `my_dict` apart and then put it back together again so it's the same (when it doesn't encounter malformed data)?

Comment: Hello, @Eduardo Carvalho, please don't leave us hanging.

Comment: Sorry, @martineau. I really appreciate your hints. The problem was solved but it wasn't related with the overwriting of python dictionary values. The cause of the error was an unsuccessful parameter passing. I apologize for my mistake. Best regards.

Comment: @Eduardo Carvalho: If, by chance, my suggestion to print the argument value helped you find the real problem, please accept it in the form of the answer I posted. Alternatively, select another answer which helped you find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dict` constructor expects a sequence of 2 item subsequences (lists or tuples).  At least one of subsequences contains more then two items.

Perhaps you have missing comma (see last item):

```
>>> dict([('1', 'red'),('2', 'blue'),('3' 'purple')]) # missing comma in last item
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#166>", line 1, in <module>
    dict([('1', 'red'),('2', 'blue'),('3' 'purple')]) 
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2 has length 7; 2 is required
```

Or maybe a single item instead of a tuple (again, see last item)

```
>>> dict([('1', 'red'),('2', 'blue'),('purple')]) # last "tuple" has one item
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#167>", line 1, in <module>
    dict([('1', 'red'),('2', 'blue'),('purple')])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2 has length 6; 2 is required
```

Comment: Very interesting example, but I checked my tuples and not noticed the absence of commas or a single term. I have things like (u'vesti\xe1rio', None), but it's running on ipython.

Comment: @user1596206: You may not have noticed an issue, but the issue exists.  Python's error message is telling the truth.  Try running the diagnostic that phihag has written for you.  I think it will make your invisible error visible.

Comment: @ Steven Rumbalski: The error message was really telling the truth. The code proposed by phihag was very useful to me, returning ValueError: In 'DOCENTE': value is not a tuple(2), but u'quadro'. So, I could detect my error occurred before and it was not related with the overwriting of python dictionary values. Thank you very much and sorry if the question does not proceed.

Answer (score 4):

The input in the real testcase doesn't conform to the structure you expect. In particular, instead of all being tuples, at least one of the elements is a sequence of length 6. For example, a faulty input may look like:

```
{'DOC': [
    [('123456')],               # A string is a sequence, too
    [('123' '456')]             # Note the lack of a comma
    [('1','2','3','4','5','6')] # A tuple, but with 6 elements
    [['1','2','3','4','5','6']] # A list
]}
```

To solve this problem, check your input, like:

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for l in v:
        for subl in v:
            for tup in subl:
                if not len(tup) == 2:
                    raise ValueError('In %r: value is not a tuple(2), but %r'
                                     % (k, tup))
```

Oh, by the way, when designing data structures, it's often a good idea to follow the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), which includes:

> Flat is better than nested.

Comment: I've used the proposed code but there isn't a sequence of 6 elements in my real tuples.

Comment: Can you simplify your real tuples until you get an input that you can show to us, but that still fails?

Comment: @user1596206:  Is it possible that you are missing a comma in one of your tuples?  `('18', 'blue')` becomes a single six item string if you forget the comma because Python implicitly concatenates two adjacent strings.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Excellent example, that's probably it. Added it to this answer, and +1 to yours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your "real code", the first element of one of your lists has more than two elements (6). `dict` requires exactly two to interpret them as `key, value`.

Here's an example that generates the error you describe:

```
my_dict = {
    'DOC': [
        [('k', 'v', 'extra1', 'extra2', 'extra3', 'extra4'), ('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k4', 'v4')],
        [('k5', 'v5'), ('k', 'v'), ('k1', 'v1'), ('k6', 'v6')]
    ],
    'DIC': [
        [('k7', 'v7'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k8', 'v8')],
        [('k5', 'v5'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2')],
        [('k4', 'v4'), ('k9', 'v9')]
    ],
    'INFRA': [
        [('k5', 'v5'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2')],
        [('k', 'v'), ('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3'), ('k4', 'v4')]
    ]
}
```

Here's a simple way to drop in a print statement to see the problem element:

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():

    # Print out the first element of each list,
    # because one of them has six elements when it should only have two.
    for l in my_dict[k]:
        print l[0]

    my_dict[k] = map(lambda x: dict(x), my_dict[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see no problem with code and data in your question. Assuming there's nothing significantly different about the "real" code, you could do something like this to find out what the malformed data is that causes the error to occur:

```
def test(x):
    print x
    return dict(x)

for k, v in my_dict.items():
#     my_dict[k] = map(lambda x: dict(x), my_dict[k])
     my_dict[k] = map(test, my_dict[k])
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this code which is simpler than yours:

```
temp_dict = {}
for k in my_dict():
    temp_dict[k] = {}
    for t in my_dict[k]:
        temp_dict[k][t[0]] = t[1]
my_dict = temp_dec
del temp_dec
```

Comment: -1 This would just mask the problem. And wrong data is usually way worse than an error.